# Exporting a Binary Search Tree to a .csv file

Tags: c++

I have a BST database that i have to export to a .CSV file. i can get it to export the first record. how can i get it to loop until the entire database is exported.

```
void get(NodeActor* node, ofstream myfile)
{
if(node==NULL)
return;
myfile << "Year , Award, Winner, name, film"<< endl;
myfile << node->year << "," << node->award << "," << node->winner << "," << node->name << "," << node->film<< endl;
get(node->left,myfile);
get(node->right,myfile);
}
void ActorBST::ExportToCSV(NodeActor *node)
{
    string fileName;
    cout << "File Name(include .csv): ";
    cin >>fileName;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (fileName);
    myfile << "Year , Award, Winner, name, film"<< endl;
        myfile << node->year << "," << node->award << "," << node->winner << "," << node->name << "," << node->film<< endl;

    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Use loops or recursion.

Comment: The simplest way is to write a recursive tree walker. Non-recursive is a little bit more complex.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ traverse binary tree".

Comment: Fun fact: `ofstream` closes when it goes out of scope. If the last thing you do in the function is close the file, you can safely leave out the explicit call and let the destructor do it for you.

Comment: i tried a loop and it just went into an infinite loop. any code suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: No one has answered this question yet, so feel free to make a significant change like adding your loop code, but first back up your code and make a [mcve]. MCVEs are a great way to distill a problem down to its barest essentials, and when you've got nothing left in the program except the bug, it's usually pretty easy to spot the bug. Might not be easy to fix, but that's when Stack Overflow really becomes useful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to call your `get` function inside the `ExportToCSV` method.
Your `get` method is already taking care of recursion, so it should work, provided that you pass the top node to `ExportToCSV`.

```
void ActorBST::ExportToCSV(NodeActor *node)
{
    string fileName;
    cout << "File Name(include .csv): ";
    cin >>fileName;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (fileName);
    get(node, myfile);
    myfile.close();
}
```

Maybe you want to make `get` a method of the `ActorBST` class, but that is not mandatory.